# Is it sensible to mark Firestore throwing functions with try! in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

Functions like `.setData(from:completion:)` and `.addData(from:completion:)` can throw an error synchronously. I haven't been able to find too much information online on what these errors could be so I'm assuming it'll only throw when encoding fails. Since it should be impossible in my code for encoding to fail I started marking these function with `try!` to disable error handling. Is this a sensible thing to do considering encoding should practically never fail in my code?

This is what I've done:

```
try! docRef.setData(from: book) { error in  
// ^ Synchronous errors aren't handled because it should be 
// impossible for encoding to fail. If it fails then I've
// done something seriously wrong in my code. Therefore                                             
// I mark it with try!

    completion(error)  // Asynchronous errors are handled
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the question here is: "How do you want to go forward when the functies **does** throw?".

If there is a sensible way to recover from this, I would just catch the error and handle it gracefully. Show an error, do nothing, etc.

If there is no sensible way to recover at all, then your only option might be to crash the app. In that case `try!` makes sense, but your users will be annoyed when it crashes.

Personally I think there is never a good excuse to let an app crash in production, unless perhaps your entire app state is borked and there are *no way* to handle this, but that's something that has never come up in my code.

Comment: What about using force unwrapping when accessing the ID of something. If I wanted to access the book's reference I would do something like: `db.collection("books").document(book.id!)`. Is this generally considered okay to do or should I *always* handle potential errors? If I should handle this as well where would it be considered okay to force unwrap or disable error handling?

Answer (score 1):

A precursor to this question is; is it sensible to use in production code and/or during development? I think it makes a difference. As Rengers said it would be annoying to users if it turns out there is some sort of a bug. On the other hand if used during testing and development I think it's an appropriate way to detect extremely rare edge case.

Nonetheless, I think it's important to mention the power of habit. You might end up on a bit of a slippery slope once you start using this.

Comment: What about using force unwrapping when accessing the ID of something. If I wanted to access the book's reference I would do something like: `db.collection("books").document(book.id!)`. Is this generally considered okay to do or should I *always* handle potential errors? If I should handle this as well where would it be considered okay to force unwrap or disable error handling?